# Searching a database in Android

Tags: java, android

Targeting 4.2 using Eclipse

I have a basic input screen that takes address book information from the user and puts it into a db table called `myAddressBook` my code for creating the table is as follows (db is the `SQLiteDatabase` declaration:

```
//MODE_PRIVATE = only this application
db = openOrCreateDatabase("AdddressBookDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
//Create the Table
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myAddressBook(Name VARCHAR, Address1 NVARCHAR, Address2 NVARCHAR, City VARCHAR, State VARCHAR, Zip INT(5), Phone INT(10));");
```

Now I have a `Search` button on the form and an `EditText` that I want to use to search my table and display the results in a list, or possibly in the original `EditTexts` used for the input. In the OnClick for the Search button, I have:

```
String searchvalue = searchEditText.getText().toString();
```

To get the string of whatever the user wants to search for. Now how do I basically say "find anything in the database that partially or fully matches `searchvalue`"?? (I am new to Android but VERY new to SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, this is answer for your question

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().
  rawQuery("select * from todo where _id = ?", new String[] { id });
```

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is good article. Please read that for getting answer for your question.